# Different height for section header UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, height, sectionheader

I have some issue with section header height, so:

In storyboard I defined prototype and I assigned it to the section header view, in Size Inspector with height "100", but I also created a method "heightForHeaderInSection" where I set "90".

The result is that simulator draws section with height 90, but when I call "self.tableView.sectionHeaderHeight" it gives me 100.

How can I get height from "heightForHeaderInSection" with 90 value programmatically?

Comment: Why you are setting static height for header? Try return tableView.sectionHeaderHeight; / return UITableViewAutomaticDimension; instead.

Comment: Thanks for response and good solution, but I asked about something different. I would get height of specific header in section to calculate something, but I don't know how.

Comment: I haven't tried this, try this if it could return the correct height for specified headerView in section.     CGFloat headerViewHeight = [self.tableView headerViewForSection:0].frame.size.height;

Comment: You can accept the answer if it solved your problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
CGFloat headerViewHeight = [self.tableView headerViewForSection:0].frame.size.height;
```